# How to invert a map?

Tags: elixir

What I have:

```
%{1 => #MapSet<[123, 234, 345, 456, 567]>,
  2 => #MapSet<[345, 456, 567, 678, 789]>}
```

What I need:

```
%{123 => #MapSet<[1],
  234 => #MapSet<[1],
  345 => #MapSet<[1,2],
  456 => #MapSet<[1,2],
  567 => #MapSet<[1,2],
  678 => #MapSet<[2],
  789 => #MapSet<[2]}
```

I cannot seem to find such a function in elixir, and my attempts to write my own aren't going so well.

Edit:

I ended up with this as my final solution:

```
Enum.reduce(x, %{}, fn {k, vs}, acc ->
   Enum.reduce(vs, acc, fn v, acc ->
     update_in(acc[v], fn
       nil -> MapSet.new([k])
       set -> set |> MapSet.put(k)
     end)
   end)
 end)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I had a few nested reduces, but I couldn't quite make it work.  Dogbert's answer was pretty close to what I was trying to get on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested `Enum.reduce/3` here:

```
map = %{1 => MapSet.new([123, 234, 345, 456, 567]),
        2 => MapSet.new([345, 456, 567, 678, 789])}

Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn {k, vs}, acc ->
  Enum.reduce(vs, acc, fn v, acc ->
    Map.update(acc, v, MapSet.new([k]), &MapSet.put(&1, k))
  end)
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
%{123 => #MapSet<[1]>, 234 => #MapSet<[1]>, 345 => #MapSet<[1, 2]>,
  456 => #MapSet<[1, 2]>, 567 => #MapSet<[1, 2]>, 678 => #MapSet<[2]>,
  789 => #MapSet<[2]>}
```

This may be slightly faster since it doesn't create a MapSet if one already exists for the key:

```
Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn {k, vs}, acc ->
  Enum.reduce(vs, acc, fn v, acc ->
    set = if set = Map.get(acc, v), do: MapSet.put(set, k), else: MapSet.new([k])
    Map.put(acc, v, set)
  end)
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Comment: (I changed the second code to be much cleaner, almost as elegant as the first one.)

Comment: If for some reason [corrupted input data], `Map.get(acc, v)` returns `false`, the `if set = ` will call `MapSet.new` and continue the execution, resulting in hard-to-detect run-time occasional glitches. It’s always better to pattern match rather then to use `if` IMHO.

Comment: @mudasobwa why would it ever return `false`? There is only one `Map.put/3` call here which only puts in a `MapSet`.

Comment: True, but it makes the code less structured. Yes, the future reader might assure themselves that there is only one `Map.put/3`, but why would we force them to think about that and explicitly check that? I do not insist on `Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1` by any means, but explicit `Kernel.SpecialForms.case/2` is always cleaner than `if`, expecting `nil` as the only falsey value.

Comment: If your map could get "corrupted" with a `false`, it can also get "corrupted" with a `nil` in which case your code will also fail in a similar manner. `Map.fetch` would be better if you really want protection against the map getting invalid values in it.

Comment: It’s mostly not about handling a corrupted map, it’s about making the code to be easily readable for future us / strangers.

Answer (score 2):

I would post the slightly modified answer by @Dogbert, that uses more idiomatic [`Map.get_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#get_and_update/3) and [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1):

```
map = %{1 => MapSet.new([123, 234, 345, 456, 567]),
        2 => MapSet.new([345, 456, 567, 678, 789])}

Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn {k, vs}, acc ->
  Enum.reduce(vs, acc, fn v, acc ->
    with {_, map} <- Map.get_and_update(acc, v, fn
      nil -> {nil, MapSet.new([k])}
      set -> {set, MapSet.put(set, k)}
    end), do: map
  end)
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `with` here? The pattern `{_, map}` will always match the return value of `Map.get_and_update/3`.

Comment: @Dogbert Well, yes and no. I treat using `with` here as kinda defensive programming. While the signature of `Map.get_and_update/3` is barely a subject to change in the future versions of Elixir, I do not want to depend on fortunetelling and therefore I prefer as explicit control flow expression as possible. Here `with` even looks better that chained map assignment and map return. It’s a matter of taste, of course, but I found myself using `with` wherever possible just to cut possible corner cases without a need to decide whether it could return anything else or not.